# Microsoft Azure Functions Nuget Package Prevent NET Library From Packing Into A Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk

I have a NET Library project that targets net462 that includes a `Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions` Nuget package. Problem is that when I pack my project into a Nuget library, it all succeeds (clean,restore,build,pack) except no .nupkg is created. If I comment out relevant code and get rid of the Nuget reference, a nupkg file is produced when I pack it.

I seem to be hitting this issue: [IN GITHUB](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/110) maybe?

The package in question - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

My direct question is - Is this a possible feature? Can you prevent your packages from being packed into Nugets? How would I know. Or in any other words, is this situation (the one described in the GitHub issue) even possible? What could be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide your use case? Why would you pack azure function to nuget ?

Comment: Can you detail the step to reproduce, starting from scratch?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I am writing a library to generate swagger for Http triggered function apps. So I must include the Functions library. The code needs a bunch of the references to inspect functions to generate Swagger.

Comment: @any updates , did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem where `dotnet pack` was not producing packages for `.csproj` files that use the `Microsoft.Functions.SDK` package.

`dotnet pack` allows you to provide `MSBuild` parameters that are respected, even if it doesn't occur in their docs, so you can force a `nuget` package to be generated by doing something like this on the command line:

```
dotnet pack --configuration Release -property:IsPackable=true
```

The functions SDK appears to have some code in it I've not spent the time to track down that forces that `IsPackable` flag to false, regardless of the value in the `.csproj`.

If you're struggling with these things in the future, you can look at the diagnostics of the `dotnet` command by appending `-v=d` (setting Verbosity to Debug) to your command line commands.

Comment: I appreciate this is thread necromancy, but y'know, it's where I landed when looking :)

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1 :open the project folder

[image]

### Step 2 : open cmd

[image]

### Step 5 : you should see a cmd that point to your project not solution directory

[image]

### Step 6 : copy and past the flowing commands

```
    PowerShell -Command "Get-ChildItem $dir | Where { $_.Name -match '.csproj'} | Select -Expand Name | out-file -encoding ASCII projectname"

    SET /p projectname=<projectname

    PowerShell -Command "(Get-Content -path ..\packages\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.1.0.24\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets -Raw) -replace 'DependsOnTargets="""RunResolvePublishAssemblies"""', '' | Set-Content -Path  ..\packages\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.1.0.24\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets"

    SET MSBuild_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

    SET PATH=%MSBuild_PATH%;%PATH%

    MSbuild %projectname% /t:Clean;Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release

    PowerShell -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path .\bin\Release\bin -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination .\bin\Release "

    PowerShell -Command "if(!(Test-Path -Path 'nuget.exe')){(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe','nuget.exe')}"

    NuGet.exe pack %projectname% -Prop Configuration=Release -MSBuildPath "%MSBuild_PATH%"

    start .
```

### Step 7 :  you should find your nupkg file

[image]

### Note : i used vs 2017 with flowing steps

#### create a new project

[image]

#### install Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

[image]

Comment: This is not a correct answer. Didn't wanna waste the bounty.

Comment: @jn1kk thanks for the  , what is the MSBuild output ?